# fatal: Unsupported command: Users.Ref "KPLUS"

Tags: git-p4, git-fast-import

I'm migrating several Perforce projects to Git. One is failing though at 18% of the process with:

> fatal: Unsupported command: Users.Ref "KPLUS"

It looks like git fast-import is trying to execute the text in the file where it should be printed (I think)

The fast-import crash report shows me

```
fast-import crash report:
fast-import process: 28327
parent process     : 28325
at Fri Sep 11 14:34:26 2015

fatal: Unsupported command: Users.Ref "KPLUS"

Most Recent Commands Before Crash
---------------------------------
....
....
  commit refs/remotes/p4/master
  committer USERNAME <EMAIL> 1175609377 +0100
  data <<EOT
* Users.Ref "KPLUS"

Active Branch LRU
-----------------
    active_branches = 1 cur, 5 max

  pos  clock name
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   1)    714 refs/remotes/p4/master

Inactive Branches
-----------------
refs/remotes/p4/master:
  status      : active loaded
  tip commit  : 307170cc21264c58ab1943c16f1d2943c1a44f45
  old tree    : 2f45d5c6d9cbe56e5f335f92b21316ad272f3504
  cur tree    : 2f45d5c6d9cbe56e5f335f92b21316ad272f3504
  commit clock: 714
  last pack   : 0


Marks
-----

-------------------
END OF CRASH REPORT
```

The text is in a xml file that doesn't seem to be well formatted, but I would assume this shouldn't matter.

Comment: Run git-p4 with --verbose and try to identify the failing changelist. There must be something unique in that changelist that is breaking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause in the commit messages. There were "EOT" lines in the message causing git-p4 script to interpret this as an End of Transaction. All next lines were interpreted as executable lines. Changing the git-p4 script from using EOT to EOM solved the issue.

Comment: That's an interesting information. It would be nice to report this as a bug in git's mailing list.

Comment: Not sure where to report this. Do you have a link for me?

Comment: Don't worry then, I'll create a small test case and submit it to the mailing list myself.

Comment: Excellent. Just let me know if you need more details/info.